# alexa phone call hash/pound sign available?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I use Alexa at home, and now it has the option to place phone calls for free within the USA or Canada.

This is initiated by saying, for example, "Alexa, call 1-XXX-YYY-ZZZZ"

However sometimes you get to an automated menu that wants a number and then either a "#" or "*" symbols. I tried saying "asterisk", "pound", and "hash" but none of these were recognized.

Is there a way to enter these symbols when using Alexa calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow this link

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=202136300

It mentions

> Note: Alexa Calling does not currently support calls to the following
>   types of numbers:
>
> ```
> Emergency services numbers (e.g. “911”)
> Premium-rate numbers (e.g. “1-900” numbers, or toll numbers)
> N-1-1 numbers / abbreviated dial codes (e.g. “211,” “411,” etc.)
> International numbers (numbers outside of the US, Canada, and Mexico)
> Dial-by-letter numbers (e.g. “1-800-FLOWERS”)
> ```

I guess Alexa does not support calls with an automated menu.